# Variable Variables in PHP from required / included files

Tags: php, class-method, require-once, variable-variables

I am writing a MVC Framework (for the purpose of learning and discovery as opposed to actually  intending to use it) and I have came across a slight problem.

I have a `config.php` file:

```
$route['default'] = 'home';

$db['host'] = 'localhost';
$db['name'] = 'db-name';
$db['user'] = 'user-name';
$db['pass'] = 'user-pass';

$enc_key = 'enc_key'
```

I load these via a static method in my `boot` class:

```
public static function getConfig($type) {
    /**
     * static getConfig method gets configuration data from the config file
     *
     * @param string $type - variable to return from the config file.
     * @return string|bool|array - the specified element from the config file, or FALSE on failure
     */
    if (require_once \BASE . 'config.php') {
        if (isset(${$type})) {
            return ${$type};
        } else {
            throw new \Exception("Variable '{$type}' is undefined in " . \BASE . "config.php");
            return FALSE;
        }
    } else {
        throw new \Exception("Can not load config file at: " . \BASE . 'config.php');
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

and then load the route like so:

```
public function routeURI($uri) {
    ...
    $route = $this::getConfig('route');
    ...
}
```

which catches the exception:

```
"Variable 'route' is undefined in skeleton/config.php"
```

now, it works fine if I make the `config.php` file like so

```
$config['route']['default'] = 'home'
...
```

and change the two lines in the method like so:

```
if (isset($config[$type])) {
        return $config[$type];
```

I have also tried using `$$type` instead of `${$type}` with the same problem.

Is there something I am overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, this function can be called only once, because it uses `require_once` and on subsequent calls you won't bring in the local variables defined in `config.php` anymore. I suspect you are getting this error on your second call to `getConfig()`.

Comment: I stand corrected, I changed it to 'require' and it worked, sorry!

Comment: Well mark this mans answer as correct! Also, ill add don't require the file in the function. Require it outside of the function and pass the config as an argument.

Comment: I originally required the file in the index.php page, I don't know why I don't still do it, I guess I was just trying new things!

Comment: Due to me using namespaces, I realised reason I didn't require the file in the `index.php` file was that I couldn't access the variables in the class because it was in a different namespace to the index file, which was quickly fixed by using `$GLOBALS[$type]`, it feels a bit messy but it gets the job done I suppose.